# How to create an active link in RSS?

Tags: xml, rss, xslt

In RSS, for example if I wanna add a link for the channel:
Part of the RSS code:

```
<link>
 <a href="http://www.nytimes.com/2009/04/10/technology/internet/10google.html?ref=technology"/>
</link>
```

And now here is the XSL code:

```
 <span> <xsl:value-of select="channel/link"/></span>
```

The problem here is that when I preview the code, the link is not actually be active in the browser (means that it is still look like normal text and cannot click on it on the browser)

Would you please help me how to make a link in RSS code so that it could be finally be active in the browser?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use

```
<link>http://www.nytimes.com/2009/04/10/technology/internet/10google.html?ref=technology</link>
```

Then in the XSLT, create an `a` tag and set the `href` attribute to that value. I don't know XSLT that well, but this might be possible or something to hash away at:

```
<span>
    <a>
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <xsl:value-of select="channel/link"/>
        </xsl:attribute> 
        Some text
    </a>
</span>
```